# Twilio video room multiple entries

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I'm trying to implement a classroom in which participants could enter and leave it as they like. The problem is, every time users leave the classroom for more than a specific time (probably 5 minutes) and they try to re-enter, a new room is created in Twilio. How can I prevent Twilio from creating a new room every time user enters and idle room?

Comment: Can I get a bit more detail on what's wrong here. If a room is empty for 5 minutes it will close and you will need to create a new one. How is that a problem? What does it stop you doing? What would you expect the default behaviour to be?

Comment: @philnash Can I somehow disable rooms to be closed if they're empty for 5 minutes?

Comment: Not as far as I know. But what would you expect the behaviour to be? Are you recording the rooms? What sort of timeout would you want? It's possible you should [talk to someone at Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) to better understand your needs here.

Comment: @philnash I want to record a session where a user may enter it multiple times, if it's left empty, the room will close and if the user wants to enter again a new room is created. It's all good at this point. The problem shows itself when I want to compose this session. Creating a composition object accepts only 1 room.sid and I can't compose the whole session this way.

Comment: I spoke with the Video team and there's no way to change the closing behaviour of a room. The only suggestion is to build a virtual participant that can call into the room and never leave. As long as the room has a participant it will stay live.